# Exception on JPA setParameter for CriteriaUpdate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

Code snippets below,

```
@Entity
public class A {    
    @Id@GeneratedValue private Long id;
    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

...

```
    tx.begin();
    em.persist(new A());
    tx.commit();

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaUpdate<A> update = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(A.class);
    Root<A> a = update.from(A.class);
    ParameterExpression<String> param = cb.parameter(String.class);

    tx.begin();
    em.createQuery(update.set(a.<String> get("name"), "julie")).executeUpdate();
    tx.commit();

    tx.begin();
    em.createQuery(update.set(a.<String> get("name"), param))
            .setParameter(param, "joe").executeUpdate();
    tx.commit();
```

`Query#setParameter` always threw out `IllegalArgumentException` from `Hibernate-entitymanager(5.2.8.Final)` below, and `Eclipselink(2.6.4)` had similar problem.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve binding for given parameter reference 
[org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.expression.ParameterExpressionImpl...]
```

**@EDIT**

- Added test w/o calling `#setParameter`, which passed through.

Comment: Just to check if the rest of the query works fine.. have you tried removing the ParameterExpression and putting the string "Joe" directly into the `CriteriaUpdate#set()` method?

Comment: If your JPA provider doesn't support a parameter in the UPDATE clause then raise an issue on the JPA provider to support it.

Comment: CriteriaBuilders in my experience are tied to one query and should not be reused between different queries.  You should create your second query with a new CriteriaBuilder and not share anything between it and the first query.